# Injected HTML not loading resources?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm dealing with what I guess would be a very unusual scenario. I need to manipulate the contents of an iFrame, and to do that, I'm playing with the its DOM. However, I'm noticing that certain elements - like CSS links, images, etc, aren't loading. My code looks like this:

```
var htmlString = "<html>resources, images, links, the whole shebang here</html>";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/xml"); //"text/xml" part is necessary

frame.contentDocument.replaceChild(doc.getElementsByTagName("html")[0], frame.contentDocument.documentElement);
```

It works, in that the elements are injected, however many resources don't have their load triggered. I know that it *should* be working, but for some reason it is not. Is there any way to trigger the load of resources?

EDIT: This seems to do the trick for now.

```
var resources = frameDOM.querySelectorAll("[href],[src]");
for(var i = 0; i<resources.length; i++){
    var resource = resources[i];

    if(resource.src != null){
        resource.src = resource.src;
    } else if(resource.href != null){
        resource.href = resource.href;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/xml"); //"text/xml" part is necessary
```

Nope, `text/xml` part is not necessary, in fact it's totally wrong in your case.

The right way to do would be

```
 var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
```

I hope you get the difference between XML & HTML.

Comment: I do, actually, but in my case it *is* required, since "text/html" strips out certain namespaced attributes that SVG requires.

Comment: Solution would be to parse & append SVG later in to the iframe.

Comment: It's not just SVG that it does that with, though. I'm going to be loading content from different sources, and I don't want "text/html" stripping things out and causing issues.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the .innerHTML() browser function ? It will parse the whole string on it's own.

Comment: innerHTML is slower than an already rendered DOM Object, especially when it comes to large HTML strings. Plus I need to make a few changes to it before it gets into the iframe. I updated my question with a solution I found.

Comment: You can create a dummy element, set it's innerHTML & do whatever modifications you want to. Also if you think that innerHTML is relatively slower in parsing, then my friend trust me browsers would be using the same DOMParser internally. Moreover I am very sure that your solution would make it a lot slower too.

Comment: Those are good suggestions, however I remember trying them and having issues. I'll reconsider them, though, so thanks.